# Defining a class method for full formal name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to define a class method in my `User` model, called `full_name`, which shows the users full name, including their title.

I have two models: `User` and `Profile`. `User` has one `profile` and `profile` belongs to `user`.

`User` stores attributes called `first_name` and `last_name`. The `Profile` stores an attribute called `title`.

In my `user.rb`, I have:

```
def full_name
  self.profile.try(:title)." #{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
end
```

This doesn't work. If I deleted the title bit it's all fine for the first and last name.

How do you add an attribute from the `Profile` model (which belongs to the `User` model) so that the formal full name can be displayed?

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work? `self.profile.try(:title)` should give you the title of the user's profile. What you get there? Did you set up the associations properly? Does your `profiles` table has a `user_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is not concatenation in ruby, so you might do `"#{self.profile.try(:title)} #{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"`. However this might give you a space at the start if there is no title (or profile).

Try this:

```
def full_name
  [*self.profile.try(:title), first_name.capitalize, last_name.capitalize].join(" ")
end
```

With the splat operator, if the title field is nil, it won't be added to the array. That way, when you put spaces in between each field, you won't get a space in front if there is no title.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the associations properly, `self.profile.try(:title)` should give you the title of the user's profile.

The way you wrote, you should get a syntax error for this:

```
self.profile.try(:title)." #{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
```

You should write the method this way:

```
 def full_name
    "#{self.profile.try(:title)} #{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
 end
```